# Google Analytics in Windows 8.1 Apps

Tags: windows, google-analytics

I wrote a js app for Windows 8.1 and now want to include Google Analytics. I followed these [instructions](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20%28JavaScript%20apps%29&referringTitle=Documentation) and it works in debug/release, but when I run the Windows App Certification Kit, i get about 50 of these API errors:

> ??0ChangedStateException@Platform@@QE$AAA@XZ in vccorlib120_app.dll is
> not supported for this application type. GoogleAnalytics.Native.dll
> calls this API.
>
> (Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store
> apps violates the Windows Store certification requirements.)

Am i missing something? Do i have to include something else?

More Infos:

- Visual Studio 2013
- Build x86, x64, ARM in WACK
- WACK 3.3 (3.4 with same error)

Comment: I would contact the author of the third party sdk, or use the measurement protocol directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thats really weird, but to pass WACK you need to **uninstall** the Windows Update **KB2976978**.

After that it passed the test.